# javascript waiting for animation to complete before the next animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I am putting together a powerpoint type web page, where the slides slide in and and of view with various animations. The animation sequence is held in an array (ultimately loaded from a database), and called using eval()

When the slide is clicked, the next set of animations is actioned, but I need each one to wait until the previous one has finished. So for the code below, when the SeqNo is 1, I want the ShowSlideLeft to wait until HideSlideRight as finished.

I have looked at callbacks and promises, but I cant get them to work as I cannot hard code the chaining events.

```
var SeqNo;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide').click(function (e) {
        ActivateSequence(++SeqNo);
    });

    SeqNo = 0;

    SetupSequence();

    ActivateSequence(SeqNo);
});

function SetupSequence() {
    Sequence = [];

    Sequence[0] = [];
    Sequence[0][0] = "ShowSlideLeft('S1');";

    Sequence[1] = [];
    Sequence[1][0] = "HideSlideRight('S1');";
    Sequence[1][1] = "ShowSlideLeft('S2');";
}  

function ActivateSequence(Seq) {
    var action;
    var element;

    if (Seq < Sequence.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Sequence[Seq].length; i++) {
            eval(Sequence[Seq][i]);
        }
    }
}

function ShowSlideLeft(div) {
    var showoptions = { "direction": "left", "mode": "show" };
    $('#' + div).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
}

function ShowSlideRight(div) {
    var showoptions = { "direction": "right", "mode": "show" };
    $('#' + div).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
}

function HideSlideLeft(div) {
    var showoptions = { "direction": "left", "mode": "hide" };
    $('#' + div).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
}

function HideSlideRight(div) {
    var showoptions = { "direction": "right", "mode": "hide" };
    $('#' + div).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000);
}
```

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Well, you know that each animation will last 1000ms, why not make each animation wait 1000ms before it's allowed to begin (if another has previously started and not ended)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass .effect() a fourth parameter callback, which is a function to be called after the animation is complete.
So you can change your custom functions by adding a callback parameter and passing it down to the `.effect` call, like this:

```
function ShowSlideLeft(div, callback) {
    var showoptions = { "direction": "left", "mode": "show" };
    $('#' + div).effect("slide", showoptions, 1000, callback);
}
```

You will also need to change `SetupSequence` and `ActivateSequence`, and I suggest that you:

- replace `eval` with `window[function_name]` to implement the actual function call
- initialize the `Sequence` array with objects rather than strings (they can be stored in db as JSON strings, so this change should not impact on the DB design)

The result would be something like this:

```
function SetupSequence() {
    Sequence = [];

    Sequence[0] = [];
    Sequence[0][0] = { action: 'ShowSlideLeft', target: 'S1' };

    Sequence[1] = [];
    Sequence[1][0] = { action: 'HideSlideRight', target: 'S1' };
    Sequence[1][1] = { action: 'ShowSlideLeft', target: 'S2' };
}
```

and

```
function ActivateSequence(Seq, Step) {
    if (Seq < Sequence.length) {
        (window[Sequence[Seq][Step].action])(Sequence[Seq][Step].target, function() {
            // when the first effect is complete, execute the next one
            ActivateSequence(Seq, Step + 1);
        });
    }
}
```

Please notice that with a slight modification you can also pass an array of parameters to the custom effect functions instead of the single parameter `target` as it is now.

And of course you'll need to invoke ActivateSequence with `ActivateSequence(SeqNo, 0)` in the `click` handler.

Comment: This looks great thanks. Not sure why at the moment, but the callback isn't firing though, so the second animation is not being performed. I will look into it later as I have to pop out. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had made a typo and just needed to add a check in the callback to make sure there was another step to perform before calling it. I have learnt stuff today - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're already using jQuery, why not use their animation API?

```
$('.some-element').animate({width:200}, 400, callback);
```

You provide an object of changes, the time in which it should execute and a callback function.